# Does Vietnam's highlands have both colder winters and hotter summers than lower lying areas?

Tags: climate

In the [climate](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Vietnam#Climate) section of Wikivoyage's guide to Vietnam, it's claimed that the highlands of Vietnam have both colder winters, and hotter summers:

> The north has four distinct seasons, with a comparatively chilly winter (temperatures can dip below 15°C/59°F in Hanoi), a hot and wet summer and pleasant spring (Mar-Apr) and autumn (Oct-Dec) seasons. However, in the Highlands both extremes are amplified, with occasional snow in the winter and temperatures hitting 40°C (104°F) in the summer.

Similar things are said [here](https://www.vietnam-travel-guide.net/vietnam-weather/)

> There are extremes in the Highlands as snow sometimes falls in the winter whilst the summer can see temperatures up around 40ºC.

and a similar thing is said in Wikipedia's article on the [geography of Vietnam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geography_of_Vietnam#Climate)

> Seasonal divisions are more clearly marked in the northern half than in the southern half of the country, where, except in some of the highlands, seasonal temperatures vary only a few degrees, usually in the 21–28 °C (69.8–82.4 °F) range.

I thought that increased altitude merely meant a consistent reduction in temperature.

Does Vietnam's highlands have hotter summers as well as colder winters compared to lower lying areas, and if so, why?